# Help proving the following proposition

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove that for each real number x, $$(x+\sqrt2)$$ is irrational or $$(-x+\sqrt2)$$ is irrational.

Now I honestly just don't know where to even go with this one. I tried to do a proof by contradiction but I couldn't get anywhere and I've also reached out to some of my classmates who also seem just as clueless as I am. So really any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.  I actually misread the question.  I thought the question was:

If $x + \sqrt{2}$ is rational then prove $x$ is irrational.  Prove the same for $-x + \sqrt{2}$.

I see the question is actually to prove that regardless as to whether $x$ is rational oro not then one, the other, or both of $x+\sqrt {2}$ or $-x + \sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

To prove that:

If $x + \sqrt{2}$ is irrational we are done.

If $x + \sqrt{2} = q$ is rational then

$x = - \sqrt{2} + q$

And $-x + \sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2} - q + \sqrt{2}= 2\sqrt{2} + q$

And as an rational(not zero)$\times$irrational + rational = irrational (see below), $2\sqrt{2} + q$ is irrational, we are done.

(the below:)

rational(not zero)$\times$ irrational + rational=rational would imply irrational = $\frac{\text{rational - rational}}{\text{rational(not zero)}}$.

Honestly, I like Jose Carlos Santos answer better, that:

$\frac {(x + \sqrt{2}) + (-x + \sqrt{2})}2 = \sqrt 2$ which is irrational. So if $(x + \sqrt{2})$ and $(-x + \sqrt{2})$ were both rational so would their average be.  Which it isn't.

Which is the same idea as mine but quite elegant and eloquent in my opinion.  Had I read the question correctly the first time, I wouldn't have bothered to answer.

I'm going to leave my answer as I think it goes into great detail of food for thought in general.

===== oops === my original answer--- to a slightly different question ====

Where to go?

The rationals are are closed under addition/subtraction and multiplication/division.

So if $x + \sqrt{2}= y \in \mathbb Q$ and $x \in \mathbb Q$ then $y-x \in \mathbb Q$.  But $y - x = (x + \sqrt{2}) -x = \sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb Q$.

And that's really all there is to it.

====

There is a very tiny caveat:

rational + rational = rational

and rational + irrational = irrational (as we just proved)

but irrational + irrational could be either.

I once thought "But maybe we can state, if $x,y$ are irrational then $x + y$ is irratioanal, unless $x$ and $y$ are "dependant" that is $x = r + q*y$ for some rational $r$ and $q$".  I even *proved* that statement and thought I had adequately expressed an important property.

Unfortunatly as $x + y = q \in \mathbb Q$ means $x = q - y$ *by definition*, my result was actually trivial and banal.  *sigh*.

Comment: Okay that makes since. I knew that rationals were closed under addition, subtraction and ect... I just didn't really know how to play off of that and that's where I was getting stuck with actually showing the math behind it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If both of them were rational, then their average would be too. But their average is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: If $x $ is rational, both are irrationals.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Indeed.

Comment: I misread the question.  If I hadn't I wouldn't have bothered posting my answer as this answers the question eloquently and elegantly.